# SQL query include elements who have Null associated with them

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to title this question, I am trying to build a query which returns a 
Count of

1. Requests
2. in a given timeframe
3. for a particular set of buildings which I have defined using an IN list

I always want ALL the buildings to appear even if there are no Requests in that time frame. 
An example might look like this:

```
| Building  | Requests Count|
|   BL 1    |     NULL      |
|   BL 2    |     14        |
```

I have figured out the query IF there are Requests in the 2 week time frame, but if there are no requests in the timeframe then BL 1 would not be included in the results.

I think I want to put my Date condition right next to the SELECT Field, because when I put it in the WHERE section it the building does is not included in the set.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Adding the query below. I have read through the suggested solutions but I am not sure they address the issue. Any more clarification would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT bl.name, wrs.bl_id, count(wrs.wr_id) as NumWRs
FROM bl RIGHT JOIN
--Subquery for Status and groups by workteam and calculates # of days open
(SELECT Reqs.wr_id, Reqs.date_requested, Reqs.bl_id
  FROM Reqs
  WHERE Reqs.date_requested >= @StartDate AND Reqs.date_requested <=  @EndDate  
  AND Reqs.bl_id IN('B00051', 'B00050', 'B00056', 'B00057', 'B00020', 'B00021', 'B00022', 
  'B00023', 'B00025', 'B00026', 'B00027', 'B00028', 'B00029', 'B00030', 'B00031', 'B00032',
  'B00033', 'B00035', 'B00036', 'B00048', 'B00100', 'B00102', 'B00120', 'B00060', 'B00164',  
  'B00181', '000182', 'B00063', 'B00058')
  )
) as wrs ON bl.bl_id = wrs.bl_id
```

Comment: add your query, otherwise it is impossible to know what your did.

Comment: what platform are you running on -- sql server, oracle, mysql, db2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your query with `select building from buildings` so you get all the rows and then left join with the results of your existing query.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use an in list.

For example you might now have:

```
 SELECT b.Name -- blah blah blha
 FROM TABLE b
 WHERE b.Name IN ('BL 1','BL 2')
```

or

```
 WHERE b.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM TABLE2)
```

But this is a problem because you always want the names.

So instead do this put your criteria in a sub-query and then do a left join from that table.

```
 SELECT b.Name -- blah blah blha
 FROM 
   ( SELECT 'BL 1' as Name
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'BL 2' as Name
   ) b
```

or

```
 SELECT b.Name -- blah blah blha
 FROM 
   ( SELECT Name FROM TABLE2
   ) b
```

You may say... but there is a where clause in TABLE2 and I don't want anything but the building name... do this:

```
 SELECT b.Name, c.RequestCount -- blah blah blha
 FROM 
   ( SELECT Name FROM TABLE2
   ) b
 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 c ON b.Name = c.Name
 WHERE c.worth > 200000
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Thanks all, I solved it by creating 2 subqueries, one with all work requests for the given time period, the other with the list of buildings (using IN list) I want to report on. Then a right join and I'm set. Thanks all for helping me think it through!